# Как в цикле forEach получить общую сумму?

Tags: javascript, html, css3, ecmascript-6

[image: Screenshot]

`echo 'Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World`

Comment: добавьте код, а не скришнот кода

Comment: вывод в консоль перенесите в саму функцию `onclick`

Comment: забыли присвоить 0 или '', в зависимости что суммируете; let res = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не до конца понятен вопрос. Но, возможно, вы ищите способ сложить числа с помощью forEach.

```js
let sum = [100, 797 , 12];
let result = 0;

sum.forEach(function(item, i) {
  result += item;
});

console.log(result);
```